# void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager) on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hello there when run or test my app I got this error on line 99 where I call `RecylerView` as list_request.

```
  list_request.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
```

so this is where i decrered it:

```
    list_request = view.findViewById(R.id.leaves_list);
    leaveList = new ArrayList<>();
    leavesListAdapter= new LeavesListAdapter(getContext(),leaveList,this);

    loadLeavesMethod();
```

and inside the `loadLeavesMethod()` is where i use this:

```
private void loadLeavesMethod() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    String URL1 = Constant.host +"/UTB_API1/req_leaves.php";
    StringRequest request= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL1, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray leaveArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int l =0; l< leaveArray.length();l++){
                    JSONObject leaveObj = leaveArray.getJSONObject(l);
                    leaveList.add(new DataLeave(
                            leaveObj.getString("TypeId"),
                            leaveObj.getString("LeaveName"),
                            leaveObj.getString("LeaveDays")
                    ));
                }
                list_request.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
                list_request.setAdapter(leavesListAdapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(request);
}
```

Comment: does `getContext()` is `null`

Comment: The error message tells you that `list_request` is null (the thing you called `setLayoutManager` on). `findViewById` can return null for a number of reasons - using the wrong view ID or view type or calling it before the layout is inflated are the most common reasons, but you haven't really provided enough context to say which is happening here (e.g. show your XML and show *where* your call to `findViewById` is in the Fragment)

Comment: @Tyler V
thank you is was working!